# Strength of bump depends of object scale?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

Look at the Blend file:

[image]

On frame 2 we have an cube with bump texture:

[image]

On Frame 1 we have same object, same material and same lightning (one sun). The only difference that this cube scaled 500 times:

[image]

As you noted the bump map on scaled object affects so small, that faсes looks flat.

Same result on different bump methods. First, Using displacement (not real geometry, experimental features turned off):

[image]

Second, with bump node:

[image]

Is it possible to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? Also since it seems you have multiple object sizes I assume you may have scaled your objects. Try applying the scale with Ctrl-A to ensure that isn't an issue.

Comment: Nice question, i will try to edit this for more understandable

Comment: Perhaps add some detail to the setup of the bumps - is it displacement modifier, cycles true displacement, etc. - without having to rely on someone downloading and opening your blend file.

Comment: @RichSedman ok, done

Comment: There's something strange about your scene, you have 2 objects Cube and Cube.001 but their mesh appear combined/joined when going to edit mode. That probably messes up the UV maps.

Comment: @user2049010 yeah this is called "linking". As i pointed (I edited question), they are "same object" - both cubes have same mesh data. I did it on purpose to show that the objects are the same, and the only difference between them in scale

Comment: where are the blender gurus or developers? is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

I think, it's a limitation of bump method. You can noted, that strength of bump effect not depends of scale, it depends of how big current face in world space...

So, use normal map. Normal map uses angles instead of depth, that's why objects, textured with normal map will looks the same in all scales.

[image]

Related: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?359453-Cycles-displacement-corruption-when-scaling-an-object

Comment: it does not completely solve the problem ... it's a bug

Comment: have more suggestions ?

Comment: how to write to developers ?

Comment: @ZiCViZ, of course, you can write a bug report, but it will close as invalid. Maybe, you describe more about what you want to do, to think about walk-around.